# Refactor function to sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

To make long story short we have this function ... it is THE FUNCTION.
It's called 'get_user_id'
What it does is getting info from context about apex login and then selecting user_id from our custom auth table.
This function has like 5yrs or even more because i can see APEX_030200 user in db user list  , and our DBA said that he created it back when he was evaling Apex for company use.

```
create or replace function get_user_id return number as
 client_info VARCHAR2(1000); 
 rezult  number;
 x_user varchar2(512);
begin
 -- return 1;
 DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.READ_CLIENT_INFO ( client_info   ); 
  x_user := substr(client_info,INSTR(client_info, ':' ,3,1)+1)     ;
 select user_id 
  into rezult
  from USERS
  where     upper(login) = upper(x_user)  ;
 RETURN  rezult ;
   EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN -1;
end;
```

So yea ... 
I tried running this query :

```
select * from (0,5 x 10^6 rows ) where user_id = get_user_id;
```

and our server took like 2 minutes to return no rows
I started reading about optimising functions in sql etc. and I worked out that I can get it down sub 0.1 sec just by :

`select * from (0,5 x 10^6 rows ) where user_id = (select get_user_id from dual );`

and then I started to analyze what's actually inside the function , face palmed , and just did

```
select * from (0,5 x 10^6 rows ) 
where user_id in ( 
   select user_id from users 
   where upper(login) = nvl(upper(:APP_USER),'SYSTEM')
)
```

Query time: 0.03 sec.

Problem solved ... but
Here goes my question
Is there any decent way to change all instances of sql in Apex  raports/item sources and db views  from

get_user_id

to

```
( 
   select user_id from users 
   where upper(login) = nvl(upper(:APP_USER),'SYSTEM')
```

)

Edit :

I`M thinking  about updating apex internal tables any1 has any experience  with it ?

Comment: If you mean global search and replace? Nothing that is supported. You have to go page by page. You can use the apex views to find all occurrences. You are encountering why I never expose raw sql or plsql on an Apex page and always wrap in a stored query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: export the application. The result will be a .SQL file - a *textual* file you can open in any text editor. Do that. Perform search/replace.

Then drop(*) the application and import it from the modified .SQL file.

(*) Drop ... with caution. I'd suggest you to first try it on a test workspace, not in production, *just in case*.

Comment: I guess this is one of options , I was thinking  about updating  apex internal tables  do you have any experience with it ?

Comment: I wouldn't dare to do that.

Comment: Additionally, you could test before/after in your pre-prod instance by importing with a different application ID.